# GDB doesn't work - not executable format?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

When trying to run gdb with `gdb ./mm.c` I'm getting the following error:

```
"0x7ffee71424c0s": not in executable format: file format not recognise
```

Does someone recognise this error and can help me to fix it?

Comment: You need to compile first: `gcc -O0 -ggdb nm.c` then `gdb ./a.out` (or maybe `gcc -O0 -ggdb -o executable nm.c` and `gdb ./executable`)

Comment: Are you trying to run source code file?

Comment: A .c file is not an executable file. It is the file that contains your source code. First compile it, then pass the executable file as input to gdb. `gcc mm.c` and then `gdb ./a.out`.

Comment: @pmg oh thanks, I'm completely new to this.

Answer (score 1):

C is (usually) a compiled language (vs. interpreted language such as (usually) JavaScript).

Your computer "speaks" `0`s and `1`s, not `for` and `if`.
The source code you write (the `for`s and `if`s) needs to be translated (compiled) to the proper `0`s and `1`s. That is the job of the compiler.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra nm.c -O0 -ggdb -oexefile
^^^                                             compile
                  ^^^^                          the fors and ifs in nm.c
                                 ^^^^^^^^^      into 0s and 1s in exefile
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                               warn about most common mistakes
                       ^^^                      do not optimize
                           ^^^^^                and output debug information for gdb
```

Then the job of the debugger is to show the `0`s and `1`s (grouped back to the original source lines when possible) as they execute, statement by statement

```
gdb ./exefile
```

With optimizations, the compiler would (very possibly) make `0`s and `1`s with no relation to the original `for`s and `if`s, making it impossible for gdb to associate them with original `for` and `if` statements.